# How do you recreate this font resizing effect?

Tags: javascript, text, resize, effect

Navigate to apple.com and resize the text (in Chrome this is `Ctrl-+`). The text at the top of the screen expands with a cool sliding effect to match the new text size. You can also see the effect on this site: http://www.thedesigncubicle.com/.

How can I recreate this effect on my site?

Comment: nice effect, i am sure you can use jquery animate() to animate the font-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, it's just the way that elements using fonts via `@font-face` rescale those fonts in Chrome at least.

Comment: This is probably correct... just realized I can't recreate the effect in Firefox.